Ajax Authorization headers or http cookies for jwt authentication
What is the best and secure way to pass Jwt token to ajax request call.
I have two options
Option 1. Pass jet token in ajax headers as below but Jwt token is visible in client response.
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "https://localhost:44360/test",  
    headers: {  
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'token22334556....'
    },  
    dataType: 'json',  
    success: function (result, status, xhr) {  
        ShowData(result);  
    },  
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {  
         alert(error);  
    }  
});

Option 2 - store Jwt token in http only cookies, that will be pass in ajax request as below. Jwt is not visible in  ajax
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
- url: "https://localhost:44360/test",
    xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   },
dataType: 'json',  
    success: function (result, status, xhr) {  
        ShowData(result);  
    },  
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {  
         alert(error);

    }  
});

Both options are working to validate request using Jwt but if anyone can help which one is best option as security point of view.

The use of JWT token provides information and claims of the user. It can be passed from HTTP headers and also from the cookie. if your payload size is large and you don't want that client should make any change you should go with the cookie, by setting that cookie to HttpOnly. If client interventions and
payload size are not your concern then go with Http headers it is also safe.
But if you want to make your application more secure then I would suggest the reduce to JWT life period.

Thank you @utsav makwana. I have less payload Jwt and have shorter lifetime. I have got both options implemented and tried. I can see access token (ajax headers) in response page that's why wanted to check which would be secure and best option.

In this case,the best option is number two.
The JWT is non-accesible in the client side, making it more secure, as per you are not risking yourself to a a XSS attack. Also, the code looks cleaner and more clever.
If you have access to the backend, you would need to do some changes depending in the option you choose.

Thank you @EDev. I have both options implemented and tried. Wanted to check which option I should go to make application secure.
